# Site for creating websites - saving progress

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I have a task to create a website that'll allow creating small websites, mostely simple html (add some text, picture positioning, buttons). So I've come up with solution to save progress the way described below.
I'll create some hierarchy of classes with some properties (like Location and size, color, font) wich will be serizlized into xml and saved into my remote database. When loading it, it'll just pasre back and create GUI for user.
So, am I doing this right, or there is some easier way to do this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a solution that allows you to output HTML, why don't you just save that? If you're the one outputting the markup you can keep it strict*, which will make it easier to parse back.

*Or, you could even use custom attributes to make parsing simpler.

Comment: you mean that I add a browser control and just show my generated html? it'll work, but how than I'll make changes to elements (like color) if I won't be able to select them. I want to add real controls to a panel, so I can select them and make changes through PropertyGrid. When user presses 'Save Progress' it'll serialize...

Comment: No, don't show the generated HTML. I'm saying just save the generated html, then read it back again. No need for xml or a separate serialization process.

Comment: I can try, thanks =) but I'll see if it'll be easy to parse back from html werther from desirialized objects...

Comment: Good luck. :) As I said, you should be able to make the parse-back easier by using custom attributes (or even just your own format for classes on elements). Check out Html Agility Pack (http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for an easy way to parse html.